# Set up angular-seed from git bash - Error: EINVAL, invalid argument : Object.<anonymous> : Exit status 8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, http, server

So here I am a java developer trying to learn Angular. Came across a lot of new stuff in this course. Now i was trying to set up angular-seed from my git bash and this error shows up when i run `npm start`. I am not quite sure where to look. Is this a node setup issue,guessing so because i done it myself as it wasn't in the tutorial. Any help is appreciated.

```html
$ npm start

> angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart F:\0-TUTS\AngularJS 2 Essential Training\Angular-Learn with 10 example\AngularWeekend\templatestore
> npm install


> angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall F:\0-TUTS\AngularJS 2 Essential Training\Angular- Learn with 10 example\AngularWeekend\templatestore
> bower install


> angular-seed@0.0.0 start F:\0-TUTS\AngularJS 2 Essential Training\Angular- Learn with 10 example\AngularWeekend\templatestore
> http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app


Error: EINVAL, invalid argument
    at new Socket (net.js:156:18)
    at process.stdin (node.js:664:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\0-TUTS\AngularJS 2 Essential Training\Angular- Learn with 10 example\AngularWeekend\templatestore\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server:159:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej                                                                                                                s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd F:\0-TUTS\AngularJS 2 Essential Training\Angular- Learn with 10 exa                                                                                                                mple\AngularWeekend\templatestore
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm
```

Adding the **npm.debug.log**

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.9
3 info using node@v0.10.28
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart angular-seed@0.0.0
6 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 info start angular-seed@0.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info angular-seed@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
10 error angular-seed@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8080 -c-1 ./app`
10 error Exit status 8
11 error Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 start script.
11 error This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
11 error not with npm itself.
11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
11 error     http-server -a localhost -p 8080 -c-1 ./app
11 error You can get their info via:
11 error     npm owner ls angular-seed
11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
12 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
13 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error cwd F:\0-TUTS\AngularJS 2 Essential Training\Angular- Learn with 10 example\AngularWeekend\templatestore
15 error node -v v0.10.28
16 error npm -v 1.4.9
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: A quick look at the repo - found this: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/issues/199. Try some of the proposed solutions there?

Comment: I checked for other process on port 8000 and also tried changing package.json. It doesn't solve the issue! http-server -a localhost -p myPortNumber -c-1 ./app seems to fail every time.

Comment: I also tried running git bash as administrator suspecting "verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true"

Comment: For some reasons the command is working from cmd. May be the git bash is having some privilege issues. Don't know how to fix that. But its working fine now!